# jqAlert Line Breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm being unsuccessful creating an alert with line breaks. I'm new to jQuery so I'm sure I'm missing something simple, which I'm also not finding via web searches.

```
jqAlert({ text: 'The item:\n\n ' + item.description + '\n\nhas already been added.', title: 'Duplicate Entry' });
```

I have also tried using \r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried using `<br />`? I would guess that it is actually rendering a html popup.

Comment: Yes! I knew I was missing something simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\n` with `<br/>` and tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: Perfect. This makes total sense because the alert box is HTML and not the same as a regular javascript alert(). I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. Thank you.